# Assign one docker container per user automatically at login (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, multiple-users

I am looking for a way to isolate my users on an **Ubuntu Server (20.04)**. I have a **base image** that is the **same for all users** connecting to the server (same base OS with a few applications). For now, I can ask my users to start the container manually, in order to isolate their executions. What I am looking for is for a more elegant way of doing it.

For instance, when an user connects to the server (i.e., SSH), I'd like to automatically instantiate the container and "connect" my user directly to the container, without passing through my host system. Mainly, I'd like to have **a virtual environment for each user**, which is automatically executed when the user connects to the server.

Is there a way to do it properly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but a try.

The tricky part is that you cannot simply dockerize the shell access as otherwise every shell would have it's own environment and you could not open a second connection to the same container.
Therefore you want to start a container when the user opens the first session, and keep that until the user's last session ends. Inbetween just the existing container will be reused.

Systemd has a feature that could be used in this szenario. Check out

- https://www.unixsysadmin.com/systemd-user-services/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/895012/running-systemd-units-in-user-space-in-debian
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508121/how-to-check-status-for-user-level-systemd-unit